# Linear regression with tensorflow is very slow

Tags: python, performance, regression, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a simple linear regression in tensorflow (with the goal of eventually extending it to more advanced models). My current code looks as follows:

```
def linear_regression(data, labels):
    # Setup placeholders and variables
    num_datapoints = data.shape[0]
    num_features = data.shape[1]
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_features])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
    coeffs = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[num_features, 1]))
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1]))

    # Prediction
    y = tf.matmul(x, coeffs) + bias

    # Cost function
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y-y_, 2))/(2.*num_datapoints)


    # Optimizer
    NUM_STEPS = 500
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    train_step = optimizer.minimize(lasso_cost)

    # Fit the model
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    cost_history = np.zeros(NUM_STEPS)
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(NUM_STEPS):
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print 'Step:', i
        for xi, yi in zip(data, labels):
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: np.expand_dims(xi, axis=0), 
                y_: np.expand_dims(yi, axis=0)})
            cost_history[i] = sess.run(lasso_cost, feed_dict={x: data,
                y_:labels})

    return sess.run(coeffs), cost_history
```

The code works, and finds the correct coefficients. However, it is extremely slow. On my MacBook Pro, it takes several minutes just to run a few training epochs for a data set with 1000 data points and 10 features. Since I'm running OSX I don't have GPU acceleration, which could explain some of the slowness, but I would think that it could be faster than this. I have experimented with different optimizers, but the performance is very similar.

Is there some obvious way to speed up this code? Otherwise, it feels like tensorflow is pretty much useless for these types of problems.

Answer (score 5):

It is so slow, since you train the network point by point which requires `NUM_STEPS * num_datapoints` iterations (which leads to **5 hundred thousands** cycles).

All you actually need to train your network is

```
for i in range(NUM_STEPS):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: data, y_:labels})
```

This would take just a couple of seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That change will of course speed up the code a lot, but if I do this, it seems to converge to completely random (and wrong solutions). I was actually meaning to ask about this as well. My initial code was training on all the data at once, but it didn't find the correct solution. I found a couple of different pieces of example code online, and they all train on each data point. For some reason, this seems to improve the convergence of the minimization? I don't really understand why though.

Comment: You use a default learning rate which might be quite high and thus lead to a non-converging result. So when you create optimizer choose a learning rate explicitly, e.g. AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001).

Comment: Well, I have already experimented a lot with different optimizers and learning rates, and no combination I have found ever gives correct results when training on the entire data set at once (I always get a model with coefficients that are completely unrelated to the ones put in). Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but if someone has or could point me to a tensorflow implementation of linear regression that works and is reasonably efficient, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Just post your data somewhere and start a bounty. Maybe the problem is in your data, not in the model itself.

Comment: Turns out that if I change the line `y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])` to `y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])`, I get the correct results when training on the entire data set at once. Still trying to figure out exactly why, but it appears this solved the problem.

Comment: Oh, yes, this is a common mistake which I missed. The thing is that [None] - is vector, while [None,1] is a matrix with 1 column. 
That is why you get different results when training by points or by batches, as (y-y_) has different shapes.

Comment: Yeah, it was just weird that it still seemed to converge to _something_, just not the correct solution. Anyway, thank you for your help!